# Change 1 element class at a time React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table with a rows that show a label, with a button. When the button is clicked the label gets a d-none class added. Simultaneously an input on the same row get its d-none class removed. I want to imitate this on ONE row at a time. right now it is updating every single row when I click on an edit button in a different row.

How can I let react know only to update element class on one row at a time?

Here is my component below

```
import React, { useEffect, Fragment, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Button,
  ButtonGroup,
  Card,
  CardBody,
  Col,
  Label,
  Input,
  Row,
  Table
} from "reactstrap";

const ContactEdit = () => {
  const [changeText, setChangeText] = useState(false);

  const contactDetails = useSelector((state) => state.contactDetails);
  const { success: successGet } = contactDetails;

  return (
    <Card className="mb-3">
      <CardBody className="bg-light border-top">
        <Row>
          <Col lg className="col-xxl-5">
            <Table bordered className="bg-white">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <Label>First Name</Label>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <row className="d-flex inline">
                      <span className={changeText ? "d-none" : "w-100"}>
                        {contactDetails?.contact?.data?.firstName}
                      </span>
                      <Input
                        className={changeText ? "mr-1 " : "d-none"}
                        default={contactDetails?.contact?.data?.firstName}
                        id="first-name"
                        placeholder={contactDetails?.contact?.data?.firstName}
                        onChange={(e) => setChangeText(e.target.value.length)}
                      ></Input>
                      <Button
                        onClick={() => setChangeText(!changeText)}
                        onMouseEnter={() => console.log("this ran")}
                        className="d-flex ml-auto"
                      >
                        {changeText ? "Cancel" : "Edit"}
                      </Button>
                    </row>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <Label>Last Name</Label>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <row className="d-flex inline">
                      <span className={changeText ? "d-none" : "w-100"}>
                        {contactDetails?.contact?.data?.lastName}
                      </span>
                      <Input
                        className={changeText ? "mr-1" : "d-none"}
                        placeholder={
                          changeText
                            ? contactDetails?.contact?.data?.lastName
                            : " "
                        }
                      ></Input>
                      <Button
                        onClick={() => setChangeText(!changeText)}
                        className="d-flex ml-auto"
                      >
                        {changeText ? "Cancel" : "Edit"}
                      </Button>
                    </row>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <Label>Phone Number</Label>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <row className="d-flex inline">
                      <span className={changeText ? "d-none" : "w-100"}>
                        {contactDetails?.contact?.data?.phone_number}
                      </span>
                      <Input
                        className={changeText ? "mr-1" : "d-none"}
                        placeholder={
                          changeText
                            ? contactDetails?.contact?.data?.phone_number
                            : " "
                        }
                      ></Input>
                      <Button
                        onClick={() => setChangeText(!changeText)}
                        className="d-flex ml-auto"
                      >
                        {changeText ? "Cancel" : "Edit"}
                      </Button>
                    </row>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </Table>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Here is a code sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/embed/magical-sara-phyxf?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: can u add a codesandbox of your this code

Comment: you can pass row id and check if row id is matching then only update that row class

Comment: @Madhuri I feel like that is the answer, just not sure exactly how to implement...